# Is an automorphic form of $\operatorname{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$ determined by its L-function?

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions

To an automorphic representation $\pi$ of $\operatorname{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$ one can associate its L-function $s\mapsto L_{\pi}(s)$.

Is the map $\pi\mapsto L_{\pi}$ bijective?

Edit March 26th, 2021: can such a bijection be seen as a fully faithful fonctor between Tannakian categories $\mathcal{C}$ whose objects are automorphic representations and $\mathcal{D}$ whose objects are L-functions suggesting every automorphism of a given object of the latter arises from an intertwinning operator? If so, can such an automorphism $\varphi$ be written as $\varphi_{\sigma}:L_{\pi}\mapsto\sigma\circ L_{\pi}\circ\sigma^{-1}=L_{\pi}\mapsto{L_{\sigma'\circ\pi\circ\sigma'^{-1}}}$ where $\sigma$ is a field automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ and $\sigma'$ the corresponding intertwinning operator?

Comment: We are dealing with irreducible representations so it is generated by the $GL_n(A_Q)$-translates of one "vector" (which concretely is a left-$GL_n(Q)$-invariant function $GL_n(A_Q)\to C$), an automorphic form, that you can choose with some concrete desirable properties, translate, or make abstract by decomposing the representation into local parts.

Comment: I think it's true at least for cuspidal automorphic reps.  If $L(s,\pi) = L(s,\pi')$, there should be some way to conclude that the local components $L(s,\pi_p) = L(s,\pi'_p)$ for almost all primes $p$.  At most of the primes $\pi_p$ is unramified and determined by its local L-function.  Then strong multiplicity one gives you $\pi = \pi'$.

Comment: Thank you. This should be also true for primitive L-functions, from Lemma 4.2 in M. Ram Murty, Selberg conjectures and Artin L-functions (1994).

Comment: Certainly true for irreducible cuspidal representations by the multiplicity one theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity-one_theorem

Comment: @GHfromMO can you conclude the local L-functions are equal if the global L-functions are?

Comment: @D_S: Yes, since the local $L$-functions are just the Euler factors of the global $L$-function. To put another way, if you restrict the Dirichlet coefficients of $L(s,\pi)$ to powers of $p$, you get $L(s,\pi_p)$.

Comment: @GHfromMO : just out of curiosity, what happens for automorphic form over $\mathrm{GL}_n(\Bbb A_K)$, when $K$ is a number field?

Comment: @GHfromMO Not quite: For number fields, you can't necessarily recover the local $L$-factors from the global $L$-function -- for example if $K$ is Galois over $\mathbb Q$, a Galois twist of $\pi$ will have the same $L$-function as $\pi$, but the local $L$-factors are permuted. This has been studied, for example by Harry Smit.

Comment: @Peter Scholze: are these permutations of local L-factors the analogue of permutations of roots of the minimal polynomial of an algebraic number? If yes, can one deduce from it that any "symmetry" of an L-function is an element of some Galois group?

Comment: It's not a symmetry of any given $L$-function -- rather, two distinct $L$-functions happen to agree (by virtue of the local $L$-factors being permuted around). But I think the whole phenomenon is even more subtle than this. One way to think about it is that the $L$-function only knows about the automorphic induction from $K$ to $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: But aren't they the same as functions from $C$ to itself?

Comment: @PeterScholze: Thank you, I agree of course. I delete my comment regarding number fields.