# Is $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathcal{M})$ a fundamental group in Grothendieck's sense?

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-theory, l-functions, fundamental-group

This question is a follow-up to [Are there infinitely many L-rigs?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372349/are-there-infinitely-many-l-rigs?r=SearchResults) and to [Is an automorphic form of $\operatorname{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$ determined by its L-function?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355240/is-an-automorphic-form-of-operatornamegl-n-mathbba-mathbbq-deter).

I copy paste a deepl translation of an old answer I got to a question of mine on a French math forum:

> The idea is that to any "space" $X$ one can associate the category of its coverings $R(X)$. If we choose a "geometric point", we have a "fiber in $x$" functor: $\omega_{x}:R(X)\to \operatorname{Set}$ which to a covering $f:Y\to X$ associates $f^{-1}(x)$. If we are given a path $\gamma:x_{0}\to x_{1}$, then, for any $y_{0}\in f^{-1}(x_{0})$, it rises to a single path $\tilde{\gamma}$ of origin $y_{0}$. Considering the end of this path, we get a point $y_{1}\in f^{-1}(x_{1})$. And this depends only on the homotopy class of $\gamma$. So we have an application that to a homotopy class of paths associates an isomorphism of fiber functors: $\pi_{1}(X;x_{0},x_{1})\to \operatorname{Isom}(\omega_{x_{0}},\omega_{x_{1}})$. Grothendieck's brilliant remark is that this application is an isomorphism! In particular, $\pi_{1}(X,x)=\operatorname{Aut}(\omega_{x})$ and the right-hand side term thus gives a purely algebraic definition (we do not use the topology of $\mathbb{R}$) of the fundamental group.
>
> Where we join Galois theory is that, if we take
>
> - "space $X$" = a field $K$ (we denote $X=\operatorname{Spec}(K)$)
> - "covering $Y$ of $X$" = finite separable extension $L/K$
> - "geometric point" = embedding $x:K\to\Xi$ into an algebraically
>   closed field.
>
> Then the associated "fiber in $x$" functor is the
> functor $\omega_{x}:L/K\mapsto \operatorname{Hom}_{K}(L,\Xi)$ which to $L/K$ associates
> its $K$-embeddings in $\Xi$. The theory applies and we find that the
> "fundamental group" of $K$ (i.e., the group of automorphisms of the
> fiber functor $\omega_{\Xi}$) is  the absolute Galois group
> $\operatorname{Gal}(K^\text{sep}/K)$ of $K$ (Galois group of a separable closure).

So I would like to know if, provided that an L-rig can be extended into a field, one can establish a parallel between the sequence of intermediate L-rigs between $\mathcal{L}_{0}$ (being the analogue of $K$) and $\mathcal{M}$ (being the analogue of $\Xi$) that would allow to say that the automorphism group/"fundamental group" of $\mathcal{L_{0}}$ is an absolute Galois group. If yes, is it provably the absolute Galois group of the rationals? Can such an analogy be built on the automorphic representation side to make the map $\pi\mapsto L_{\pi}$ an isomorphism of coverings, so as to view the symmetries of a given L-function as arising from intertwining operators?

Comment: Yes, I'll fix it within an hour.

Comment: What is "a deepl translation"?  Also, I did some TeXing and other light editing per @M.G.'s [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/388649/is-operatornameaut-mathcalm-a-fundamental-group-in-grothendiecks-sense#comment989733_388649).  I hope it was all right.  (It got rolled back by a later edit, but that appears to have been a collision rather than an intentional rollback.)

Comment: @LSpice: https://www.deepl.com/en/translator Also, it seems like you overwrote each other's edits. There is a version of the question that makes the parallels more explicit.

Comment: Deepl is an automatic translation tool, more accurate than Google translate. The original answer was in French, and not everybody here can read it.

Comment: @M.G., it seems that the edits just collided, so I incorporated the added paragraph into a second edit.  I hope the edit was welcome, but, if not, easy enough to roll back!

Comment: I don't want to ruin Lspice's efforts whose editing of the Latex is really neat, but it seems to me that it's important to underline that the "base L-rig" $\mathcal{L}_{0}$ generated by $1$ and $\zeta$ is analogous to $K$, and the maximal L-rig $\mathcal{M}$ analogous to $\Xi$.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/388649/is-operatornameaut-mathcalm-a-fundamental-group-in-grothendiecks-sense#comment989753_388649), no ruining done!  Of course, make any further edits or rollbacks as appropriate.  I just wanted to help clean up, not to obscure or undo any changes you made.  (Oh, I see, I missed part of your change from [revision 4](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/388649/4)!  I tried once more—sorry for my clumsiness!—and it is included in [the current revision](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/388649/6).)

Comment: No worries, it's perfectly fine now.